# how to send data from firestore to real-time database

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, alexa-skills-kit

I am doing an IOT project for which I am adding Google Assistant and Alexa, now Google Assistant I was able to use real time database (Firebase) to change the response depending on the voice command but when it comes to Alexa I was able to pair the AVS (Amazon Voice Service) with Firestore (cloud storage) but I am unable to find a way to send the voice command request to real-time database (Firebase).

I need a way to send request from Firestore to Firebase to change the response. If anyone can help me out that would be great. My customers are waiting for the project.

Comment: Cloud Firestore and Cloud Storage are different products. You might want to check which one you actually connected to and update your question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic connection between Cloud Firestore (or Cloud Storage) and the Firebase Realtime Database. All of them have great APIs to, so you can write code to connect them yourself. But there's no built in click-to-connect feature.

Comment: to be honest this is my first project that invloves iot, firebase and firestore and i am new to writing APIs. I was able to find few source codes but so far no luck . Thats why i am reaching out if you can share a code sample on connecting firestore to firebase that would be of great help @Frank

Comment: Sorry, but that is a bit beyond what we can reasonably do here on Stack Overflow. I recommend searching for some tutorials on reading from Firestore, and writing to Realtime Database. In fact, the [Firebase codelabs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/samples/#codelabs) might be a good place to start. If you get stuck on a specific problem in the code, we might be able to help more concretely.